# C++ inheritance

Tags: class, c++11, inheritance

I have a C++ question about inheritance.

```
class X{
public:
 X()
 {
   cerr << "X()|";
 }
 X(const X& c)
 {
   cerr << "X(const X&)|";
 }
 ~X()
 {
   cerr << "~X()|";
 }
 X& operator=(const X& c)
 { 
   cerr << "X::op=|"; return *this;
 }
};

class B{
public:
 B()
 {
   cerr << "B()|";
 }
 B(const B& c):x1_(c.x1_)
 {
   cerr << "B(const B&)|";
 }
 virtual ~B()
 {
   cerr << "~B()|";
 }
 B& operator=(const B& c)
 { 
   cerr << "B::op=|"; 
   x1_=c.x1_;
   return *this;
 }
private:
 X x1_;
};

class D:public B{
public:
 D()
 {
   cerr << "D()|";
 }
 virtual ~D()
 {
   cerr << "~D()|";
 }
 private:
 X x2_;
};
```

**Question 1:**

When I run `B *pb = new B()`, the result is `X()|B()|`.

When I run `D *pd = new D()`, the result is `X()|B()|X()|D()|`.

Why is that? `B` is not a child class of `X`.

**Question 2:**

First I run `D d(*pd)`.

When I then run `*pd = d`, the result is `B::op=|X::op=|X::op=|`

When I then run `*pb = *pd`, the result is `B::op=|X::op=|`

Why does `*pd = d` have two `X::op=|` and `*pb = *pd` only have one `X::op=|`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)  `B` contains a private instance of `X` (named `x1_`).    That instance will be constructed in the process of constructing a `B`.    Constructors for bases (in any) are invoked first, then for members, then the containing class.   So constructing a `B` will invoke `X`'s constructor first, then `B`'s constructor.   Constructing a `D` will construct the `B` first (which constructs `B`'s private `X`, then invokes `B`'s constructor) after which it constructs `D`'s private `X` (named `x2_`), and then invokes `D`'s constructor.

2) `*pd = d` assigns a `D`.  Since a `D` contains two instances of `X` (the private member named `x2_` of `D` and the one inherited from `B`) the compiler-generated assignment operators for `D` will call `X::operator=()` for both.  `*pb = *pd` does object slicing and only invokes `B::operator=()` regardless of the fact that `*pd` is of type `D`.

Answer (score 1):

A1) `B *pb = new B()` result: `X()|B()|` because in order to construct `B`, an object of `X` has to be constructed first. This is because `B` privately **contains** `X`.

A2) I am not sure what you are asking! Kindly elaborate more.

EDIT:

When you're doing `*pd = d`, you are assigning `d` to an instance of `D` (*pd). Now, `D` contains an `X` privately, and also inherits from `B` (which contains another `X`). Hence, the two calls to `X`'s assignment operator.

Now, when you're doing `*pb = *pd`, you are assigning `*pd` to an instance of `B` (*pb). `D` is of type `B` due to inheritance. So, only the things that are specific to `B` are assigned to `*pb`, skipping the ones that are only part of `D`'s object ([object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)). Hence, just the one call to `X`'s assignment operator.

Comment: why is *pd = d have two X::op=| and *pb = *pd only have one X::op=|?